# Junior Software Engineer (C++) Interview Advice

Tags: c++

Hey guys.Tomorrow I have a phone interview with a good company for a Junior Software Engineer position. I have been out of the university with a bachelors for 3 months now, and am a bit rusty on my C++, as it has been a few semesters since I worked with it. I am currently reviewing it (working on pointers at the moment) to be prepared for tomorrow. Below is the description of the job. What would people recommend I brush up on the most to be prepared for the interview? What type of questions do you think the interviewer would ask that I should be sure to be prepared for? Thanks much. This would be huge for me.

Responsibilities

- Willingness to accept new challenges and learn on the job in a fast paced environment
- Opportunity to become heavily involved in all phases of the development cycle in a very short time period
- You will gain hands on experience from day one while working in conjunction with other developers to ensure a high level of quality
- Through quality testing and real world feedback, continuously improve the software*s functionality and performance

Skill Requirements

- Bachelor*s degree required in Computer Science/Engineering, or any science/engineering field with relevant programming knowledge
- Experience programming in C/C++
- Ability and desire to learn quickly and adapt to new technologies
- Familiar with polymorphism, memory allocation/de-allocation, and common data structures
- C# experience is a plus
- Network knowledge is a plus
- Knowledge of financial terms is a plus

Comment: I don't think this question is in the scope of stackoverflow. Please refer to the FAQ.

Comment: Remind them that you are cheap labor (compared to the older, more experienced folk) and that you can adapt and learn quickly.

Comment: All the best! Wish you good luck!

Answer (score 10):

If your C++ experience is a few university courses and that's a while ago, and if you need to brush up on pointers again, then that means you used to know a few things about C++, but need to learn a lot before you'll be a yearling.
If I were you, I would be open about this. Then it comes down to how much you can convince them that you are a quick learner.

Of course, they might not want to hire someone who's not up to it immediately.

Comment: Have to agree with this.  C++ is way too big a language to re-learn in a day.  They could ask you literally anything ("what's a virtual destructor?", "what's private inheritance?", "what's virtual inheritance?", "what's a copy constructor?", "what's the difference between `std::vector` and `std::list`?").  The list is endless.

Comment: If you need to "brush up on pointers", than you are a beginner and should thus start at the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Just admit that you aren't experienced with C++ or C, but that you can handle it well and you've been exposed to it before. Emphasize examples in your past where you have accomplished something that took persistence and learning a new skill/field within a reasonable amount of time. I think most employers don't expect university graduates to be very experienced programmers, just simply fresh new minds. Use that to your advantage.

Answer (score 1):

24 hours is sort of a short notice to start preparing for a technical interview.

Read about what you feel you need the most but I'd suggest to drop it. It's always a good advice to take some easy time before an interview.

Behave naturally and honestly. When they ask you about the things you don't know try to think of the solution but if it doesn't come to you just outline your current ideas and admit you don't know/remember it. It's an important personal quality in our job to be able to admit you don't know everything and ask/look for information instead of persisting in your ignorance.